# AS3 What's wrong with Timeline Code?

Tags: actionscript-3, timeline

I'm new to AS3 and have been putting my code on the timeline and everything seems to be working fine (apart from the usual issues learning a language).

What I'm wondering is why so many threads say don't put code on the timeline? Can someone recommend some resources for me to get a good birdseye view of best practice programming in AS3 and why?

Comment: Related: [Placing AS3 code on stage/MC timelines a la AS2 instead of in classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960326/placing-as3-code-on-stage-mc-timelines-a-la-as2-instead-of-in-classes) (is it a duplicate?)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've kind of jumped into the deep end a bit and I'm not a programmer by trade. Perhaps I need AS3 for dummies or something similar - if it exists!

Comment: I'm happy to mark this as answered as it offers some useful links but there's nowhere for me to "tick". I don't think the link is a duplicte in that, I wasn't familiar with AS2, so it wouldn't have helped me as a newb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

writing code in timeline can be quicker to start.  writing proper code might take longer to setup but later when you want to make any changes or additions it is much easier and sensible.  timeline code is hard to track down when the project gets complex.