# What's the proper way to program in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've read a lot of books and watched videos on AS3 and they all teach very interesting techniques that I can harness and use. However, I'm in slight confusion because I've seen different techniques that contradict each other from different sources. For example, I've seen some developers write all their code within the timeline and handle it that way. Other times, I've seen developers handle their code in an .as file in Flex/Flash Builder/FlashDevelop. I know that there is no "right or wrong" way to do it, but what is the more preferred way by professionals?

As of now, I just use my .FLA to hold my assets and I write all my code in .AS.

Comment: Related: [Placing AS3 code on stage/MC timelines a la AS2 instead of in classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960326/placing-as3-code-on-stage-mc-timelines-a-la-as2-instead-of-in-classes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Major projects shoulds strive to avoid timeline code at all times, since it will quickly become very hard to maintain, understand and version control. In these projects FLA's are mostly used to hold library assets, which are then linked into the project via swc-files.

It's fine to use FLA timeline code for small stuff like banners though.

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe that's why I saw them coding within the .FLA, they were pretty small projects. The bigger projects I saw were coded externally. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: Apart from it being very tedious to hunt down particular code fragments within nested movie clip frames, using a FLA file to hold your code forces you to manually keep regular backups, and makes working simultaneously with more than one developer virtually impossible, because the binary nature of FLA files prevents proper code versioning. You should - even for your assets - always use the uncompressed .xfl format, if your version of Flash allows you to.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way is to use Object oriented programming (OOP) with design patterns (DP).

EDIT:

From Wikipedia:

> Design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in software design.

In my opinion design patterns are integral part of OOP (without DP you loose most of the advantages of Object oriented language).

You can learn design patterns for AS3 from this great book: [ActionScript 3.0 Design Patterns: Object Oriented Programming Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528469). This book has an active [blog](http://www.as3dp.com/) with lots of interesting articles.

Comment: I understand what Object Oriented Programming is, but what are Design Patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely try to avoid timeline code if you can. It can really become a nightmare to read or expand. Using classes is a great way to start branching out of flash as well. As you get comfortable with referencing external files it is important to start using design patterns such as [MVC (Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It makes maintenance, debugging, expansion and handing off projects easier.